# Assembly language move.l p, -(A3)

Tags: assembly, 68000

I'm learning assembly language (m68000).

I don't understand the following syntax

```
move.l p, -(A3)
```

What's the difference between this and the following?

```
move.l p, (A3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different versions of *Address Register Indirect* addressing mode, however, the first one has a pre decrement.

> This addressing mode specifies the operand in memory, the address of
>   which is specified by one of the address registers. Before the operand
>   is used, the value in the address register is decremented according to
>   the size of the operand.

[Source](http://physinfo.ulb.ac.be/cit_courseware/asm/mc68000.htm)

So the difference in your example is that the address stored in the `A3` register would be decremented by `4` (the size of the operand, long word) before `p` is copied into it.